# how to expect greater than or equals in protractor

Tags: protractor

```
var Total = Rows.count();
var NewTotal = NewRows.count();

 Promise.all([ Total , NewTotal ]).then(function(lengths) {
       expect(lengths[0]>= lengths[1]).toBeTruthy();
                                });
```

This Test Fails `Expected 16 to be greater than 16.` Not sure how to change this to compare greater than or equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var Total = Rows.count();
    var NewTotal = NewRows.count();

    Promise.all([Total, NewTotal ]).then(function(lengths) {
        expect(Total).not.to.be.lessThan(NewTotal);
    });
```